# What is more pythonic? attribute querying or subclassing?

Tags: python

I want to create class than can take either a float for epsilion or an epsilion that has some decaying method.

```py
class DoSomething:
    def __init__(self, epsilion):
        self.epsilion = epsilion

    def something(self):
        # other code
        # then call decay
        decay(self.epsilion)



ds1 = DoSomething(0.2)
ds1.something()

ds2 = DoSomething(DecayingEpsilion(0.2))
ds2.something()
```

Which is more pythonic?

Subclassing like this

```py
class EpsilionWithDecay(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def decay(self):
        ...

def decay(ep):
    if isinstance(ep, EpsilionWithDecay):
        ep.decay()
```

or checking the variable for the callable method

```py
def decay(ep):
    if isinstance(ep, object) and hasattr(ep, 'decay') and callable(ep.decay):
        ep.decay()
```

Comment: What should happened if I pass an `ep` without a decay method? It looks like it just silently continues. You don't see code like this so often in python — I think that's because we would expect an error when trying to access a non-existent property. Aside for that, I prefer the second because it allows duck typing which is common. You might opt for a `try/except` instead of explicit checking.

Comment: crucial to understand, `isinstance(ep, object)` is **always true** so it never makes sense to write that

Comment: This question is opinion based and as such does not belong on SO. Still, I'll give you my opinion: both approaches are wrong. There is no reason for this function to accept two incompatible types - that just makes the code less understandable.

Comment: @zvone I will keep your suggestion in mind in the future

Answer (score 1):

It's more Pythonic for a function that accepts objects of different data types to be normalized to one standard data type first before proceeding with the same set of logics based on the standard data type:

```
class DecayingEpsilon:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def decay(self):
        ...

class DoSomething:
    def __init__(self, epsilon):
        if not isinstance(epsilon, DecayingEpsilon):
            epsilon = DecayingEpsilon(epsilon)
        self.epsilon = epsilon

    def something(self):
        self.epsilon.decay()

ds1 = DoSomething(0.2)
ds1.something()

ds2 = DoSomething(DecayingEpsilon(0.2))
ds2.something()
```

Answer (score 0):

"more" or "less" pythonic is quite subjective, for me "pythonic" means 1) KISS, 2) be explicit.

If you decide to go with runtime dispatch, there are a few options, for example:

```
def decay(eps: DecayingEpsilion | float):
    match eps:
        case DecayingEpsilion():
            eps.decay()
        case float():
            print('float!')
```

or, to satisfy your inner Javaist

```
from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable

@runtime_checkable
class Decayable(Protocol):
    def decay(self): ...


def decay(eps: Decayable | float):
    match eps:
        case Decayable():
            eps.decay()
        case float():
            print('float!')
```

or using multimethods (https://pypi.org/project/multimethod/):

```
from multimethod import multimethod

@multimethod
def decay(eps: DecayingEpsilion):
    eps.decay()

@multimethod
def decay(eps: float):
    print("float!")
```

For me personally, a cleaner solution would be to avoid method-level dispatch and force a conversion at the construction time, as @blhsing suggested. To be explicit, I'd add factory methods for different argument types:

```
class NonDecayingEpsilon:
    def __init__(self, eps: float):
        ...
    def decay(self):
        ...
    
    
class DoSomething:
    def __init__(self, eps: DecayingEpsilion | NonDecayingEpsilon):
        self.eps = eps
    
    @classmethod
    def from_float(cls, eps: float):
        return cls(NonDecayingEpsilon(eps))
        
    @classmethod
    def from_decaying_epsilon(cls, eps: DecayingEpsilion):
        return cls(eps)
```

Comment: Thanks for the write up, I learned some stuff about Python that I didn't know existed.  I have spent most of my time in other languages and Python has always been a support language for my work.